# Como sobrescrever uma pagina com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

A pergunta é simples. Eu utilizo o Ajax Javascript para pode carregar conteúdos, porém como eu posso por exemplo,carregar uma outra página html2 e fazer a página que carregou o html2 sumir?

A pergunta, o ajax tem a capacidade de carregar conteúdos em tempo-real enquanto some com o anterior?

Como se fosse clicar em um link de redirecionamento, mas sem recarregar a pagina com o conteúdo novo.

Comment: está à procura de `window.location = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions'`?

Comment: Ola, Pode ser mais explicito  com exemplos seria mais facil entender a sua questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asura, é possivel sim, inclusive este é o principio do SPA.

se você tiver um numero pequeno de paginas, pode ser interresante você carregar todos os scripts necessarios para as n paginas.

vamos olhar o exemplo abaixo:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="type/javaScript">
            var scripts = {};
        </script>
        <script type="type/javaScript" src="../scripts/core.js" />
        <script type="type/javaScript" src="../scripts/page1.js" />
        <script type="type/javaScript" src="../scripts/page2.js" />
        <script type="type/javaScript" src="../scripts/page3.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**core.js**

```
scripts.core = {};
scripts.core.container = document.getElementById("container");
scripts.core.getPage = function (url, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open("GET", url);
    httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
                container.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                callback();
            } else {
                alerta("ocorreu um erro ao carregar a pagina");
            }
        }
    })
    httpRequest.send(); 
}

document.addEventListener("readystatechange" = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    scripts.core.getPage("/page1.html", scripts.page1.onload);
  }
}
```

**page1.js**

```
scripts.page1 = {};
scripts.page1.onload = function () {
    var btPage2 = document.getElementById("btPage2");
    var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    var btAlerta = document.getElementById("btAlerta");

    btPage2.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        scripts.core.getPage("/page2.html", scripts.page2.onload);
    });

    btAlerta.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        alert("Alerta na pagina 1: o valor do input é: " + txtInput.value))
    });
}
```

**page2.js**

```
scripts.page2 = {};
scripts.page2.onload = function () {
    var btPage1 = document.getElementById("btPage2");
    var btPage3 = document.getElementById("btPage2");
    var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    var btAlerta = document.getElementById("btAlerta");

    btPage1.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        scripts.core.getPage("/page1.html", scripts.page1.onload);
    });

    btPage3.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        scripts.core.getPage("/page3.html", scripts.page3.onload);
    });

    btAlerta.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        alert("Alerta na pagina 2: o valor do input é: " + txtInput.value))
    });
}
```

**page3.js**

```
scripts.page3 = {};
scripts.page3.onload = function () {
    var btPage2 = document.getElementById("btPage2");
    var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    var btAlerta = document.getElementById("btAlerta");

    btPage2.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        scripts.core.getPage("/page2.html", scripts.page2.onload);
    });

    btAlerta.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        alert("Alerta na pagina 3: o valor do input é: " + txtInput.value))
    });
}
```

note que nesta abordagem, você deve evitar declarar variaveis no escopo global. por exemplo, no lugar de fazer `[window.]variavel = <alguma coisa>;`, faça  `[window.]scripts.pagen.variavel = <alguma coisa>;`, isto é necessario para evitar comportamentos indesejados.

note que estou usando o `scripts.pagen.onload` de forma semelhante do `$(function () { })` do jquery, ele será executado assim que a pagina estiver carregada.

por fim um exemplo das paginas:

**page1.html**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pagina 01</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            Texto: <input id="txtInput" type="text" />
        </label>
        <input id="btAlerta" type="button" value="Exibir Alerta" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btPage2" type="button" value="Ir para a pagina 2" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**page2.html**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pagina 02</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            Texto: <input id="txtInput" type="text" />
        </label>
        <input id="btAlerta" type="button" value="Exibir Alerta" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btPage1" type="button" value="Ir para a pagina 1" />
        <input id="btPage3" type="button" value="Ir para a pagina 3" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**page3.html**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pagina 03</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            Texto: <input id="txtInput" type="text" />
        </label>
        <input id="btAlerta" type="button" value="Exibir Alerta" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btPage2" type="button" value="Ir para a pagina 2" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

se precisar de um menu na aplicação, coloque ele fora da `div#container` e carregue os seus eventos no `core.js`.

quanto ao CSS, você pode fazer algo semelhante... como colocar uma classe no elemento raiz de cada pagina, como pode exemplo `class=".pagen"` e no CSS, no lugar de `<seletor> { ... }`, faça `.pagen <seletor> { ... }`.

Lembrando que esta é apenas uma forma de faze-lo, você pode carregar os scripts junto das paginas, ou pode fazer a carga apenas do dados e manter os templates ja carregados, ou até mesmo carregar os scripts sobre demanda, caso o mesmo não esteja carregado, esperar pelo carregamento do mesmo antes de carregar a pagina.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso de uma maneira simples, usando [**jQuery**](https://code.jquery.com/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
 });

function openPage(pagina, id) {
  $('.loader').show();
  $('#'+id).load(pagina);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPage('suapagina.php', 'elemento');">
  Abrir Sua página
 </a>

<div id="elemento"><img src="loader.gif" class="loader" border="0"></div>
```